# Persona matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-mining

I have a project to match two groups of people.  Under insurance, if the initial sales agent leaves the insurer, their customers will become so-called “orphan customers”. I've given a big data set containing 100,000 customers with matched agencies (13k agencies in total), for each customer and each agency, it provides related information such as nationality, marital status, gender, etc. 50 variables in total. My task is to build a logistic model and then use the model to match the optimal agency to each new incoming customers, in the dataset of incoming customers, it only provides the customer profile, but the logistic model has involved the agency profile as well. I don't know how to match the optimal agency. I've tried to match each of the agency to each new customer, for example, for new customer NO.1, I combine his profile with each of the 13k agencies, so I fit the data 13k times by using the built logistic model to calculate the probability and choose the agency with the highest result. But there are 30k new customers, my computer runs a whole day but cannot run it out, is there any matching algorithm to match the optimal agency? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly something helpful can be find in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)  direction, bipartite case.

Comment: This sounds like too broad a task.  Our site is for focused questions that can be specified precisely and answered in a few paragraphs -- and hopefully will be useful to others in the future -- so I suspect you need to break this down into smaller parts before this is suitable here.  In addition, you haven't defined what you mean by "optimal", so the problem as you've stated it here is not answerable without further information.